# How to automatically transfer color rows another sheet in execl?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I do work on 2 sheets .If I change row  color in red on one sheet, it will automatically transfer on another sheet in MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select multiple worksheets by pressing Control and clicking on the worksheet names:
   [image]
2. Select the row, on which you want to change the background, and apply the background colour as usual. Excel will apply your change to all selected worksheets.

Comment: Thanks for reply.but I want only color rows on another sheet.example I have total 200 rows on sheet1 and 20 rows are red in sheet1.I want only 20 red rows on sheet2 automatically.

Comment: You need to set up Conditional Formatting on required rows in sheet2, and to use a formula that will check some value in sheet1.